# kdb5_util: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file while initializing Kerberos code

Tags: centos, kerberos

I have this file and when I execute the coammand kdb5_util create -s I get the error"Improper Format"

Here is the file

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = ITZGEEK.COM

 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
  ITZGEEK.COM = {
   kdc = krbserver.itzgeek.com
   admin_server = krbserver.itzgeek.com
  }

[domain_realm]
 .itzgeek.com = ITZGEEK.COM
 itzgeek.com = ITZGEEK.COM

[appdefauts]
 pam= {
  debug = true
  validate = false
 }
```

Here ie my kdc.conf file

```
default_realm = ITZGEEK.COM
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 88
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 ITZGEEK.COM = {
  master_key_type = des-hmac-sha1
  default_principal_flags = +preauth
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /etc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal \
  arcfour-hmac:normal des-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-md5:normal des-cbc-crc:normal
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

krb5.conf file looks OK

There must be a typo in your **kdc.conf** file. Fix it and then restart the KDC daemon for changes to take effect.

> The kdc.conf file supplements krb5.conf for programs which are
>   typically only used on a KDC, such as the krb5kdc and kadmind daemons
>   and the kdb5_util program

Source: [MIT Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/conf_files/kdc_conf.html)

Comment: I checked the file you mentioned. I don't see anything.  I have updated the question with the content of the kdc.conf file. I don't see any changes.

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts, try to remove `default_realm = ITZGEEK.COM` on kdc.conf file

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts, if you found the answer could be useful for others don't forget to upvote ;)